# Deploy Existing Docker Image To Heroku

Tags: heroku

I am unable to deploy an existing docker image to Heroku.

Image

```
docker run -it --name xp-home enonic/xp-home
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --volumes-from xp-home --name xp-app enonic/xp-app
```

The steps I took to do it.

```
heroku login
sudo heroku container:login
sudo docker tag dpd-image registry.heroku.com/hidden-mountain-63983/web
sudo docker push registry.heroku.com/hidden-mountain-63983/web
heroku open -a hidden-mountain-63983
```

What Am I doing wrong here?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll answer this for others that might have the same question.

As per the [Heroku Container Registry & Runtime (Docker Deploys)](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#releasing-an-image) documentation, you need to release the image. In your case

```
heroku container:release registry.heroku.com/hidden-mountain-63983/web
```