# Heroku deploy from existing docker image

Tags: docker, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a GitHub bot on Heroku, using an existing docker image.

The image is already built. What I've done to try to deploy it to Heroku:

```
$ heroku login
Logging in... done
Logged in as EMAIL
$ heroku container:login
Login Succeeded
$ docker tag IMG_ID registry.heroku.com/APP/web
$ docker push registry.heroku.com/APP/web
The push refers to repository [registry.heroku.com/APP/web]
ABC: Layer already exists 
XYZ: Layer already exists 
...
lastest: digest: sha256:NUMBER size: SIZE
$ heroku container:release registry.heroku.com/APP/web
Expected response to be successful, got 404
```

And no release is done.

I've based these steps on https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#release-phase and [Deploy Existing Docker Image To Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47127765/deploy-existing-docker-image-to-heroku), but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

At this point I'm pretty stuck, any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Docker pull:

```
$ docker pull registry.heroku.com/APP/web
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from APP/web
Digest: sha256:NUMBER
Status: Image is up to date for registry.heroku.com/APP/web:latest
```

Heroku run:

```
$ heroku run bash --type=web
Running bash on ⬢ APP... up, web.1514 (Free)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your release command is malformed: you shouldn't specify the full image label, just the dyno type.

What works for me is
`heroku container:release web -a <app>`

It seems that you can't specify the image version / tag directly; `container:release` always takes the `latest` tag.

Comment: well, I get "No command specified for process type web", which is a new error at least. Not sure how to specify a command for process type web.

Comment: Have you done `heroku stack:set container`?  (from this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55884164/heroku-cli-no-command-specified-for-process-type-web-when-releasing-container)

Comment: Yes, I tried that but it didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score -1):

In ruby on Rails yo can write Procfile to especify process types
like this:

```
web: rails s
worker: rake jobs:work
```