# Heroku CLI "No command specified for process type web" when releasing container

Tags: docker, heroku

I am deploying a .Net Core application using Docker Containers.

I was able to push the image successfully using `heroku container:push web`

But calling `heroku container:release web` returns `No command specified for process type web`.

I'm a bit stumped I've tried adding `heroku.yml`

```
setup:
  addons:
    - plan: heroku-postgresql
      as: DATABASE
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
  config:
    ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: development
run:
  web: dotnet Api.dll
```

On the root directory but still no luck.

I can confirm that the image was created I'm seeing this in docker

```
REPOSITORY                                     TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
registry.heroku.com/immense-temple-11020/web   latest              5cb62a9af317        16 minutes ago      272MB
```

If anyone could point me to the right direction, it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you may need to add release section in your heroku file, can you show the full heroku.yml file.

Comment: Hi @captainchhala the full heroku.yml is the one I've included above. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: what command did you run to see the pushed image?

Comment: @LoganYang `heroku container:release web -a <name of app>` check here for details https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the reason after searching for hours.

Apparently if forgot to call 
`heroku stack:set container`.

Now I'm able to deploy and release!

Comment: I have the same problem, `heroku container:release web` gives `No command specified for process type web`. I tried `heroku stack:set container` but no change. Any idea what could go wrong?

Comment: @LoganYang what errors are you getting after `heroku stack:set container`?

Comment: It didn't give any error just `Stack set. Next release on ⬢ my-rasa-bot will use container.` Right after this, I ran release web and got the error.

Answer (score 2):

Did you have a `CMD` directive specified at the end of your Dockerfile? If not, that was likely causing the problem, which you then worked around by using `heroku.yml` and `heroku stack:set container`.

Heroku is unclear on this in their documentation. I was able to get my container to run locally without a `CMD` directive, likely as you were. But if you read Heroku docs [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#dockerfile-commands-and-runtime) or [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml#getting-started) you'll pick up that Heroku takes for granted that the Dockerfile will specify a `CMD` to run.

I had the same problem until I added the `CMD` directive at the end of my Dockerfile. I'm still working though what exactly I should put as my `CMD` directive but I no longer get the `No command specified for process type web` error.

Since you switched to using `heroku.yml` you were able to get around the `CMD` by using

```
run:
  web: dotnet Api.dll
```

Heroku docs [say](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml#getting-started) "If you don’t include a `run` section, Heroku uses the `CMD` specified in the Dockerfile."