# "No command specified for process type web" on Heroku

Tags: docker, heroku

I did `heroku container:push web` and it gives `Your image has been successfully pushed. You can now release it with the 'container:release' command.` Then I ran `heroku container:release web` and it says

```
No command specified for process type web
```

I also tried `heroku stack:set container` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55884164/heroku-cli-no-command-specified-for-process-type-web-when-releasing-container) but no change.

I have Profile as

```
web: gunicorn app:app --log-file=-
```

Not sure what's wrong and how to debug this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you have Procfile in the code?

Comment: @svikramjeet yes, I updated the post with the Procfile

Comment: web: gunicorn --chdir my_folder my_module:app

Comment: I did successfully deploy with this Procfile several times. This time I made some changes to my Dockerfile and changed to ENTRYPOINT with a bash script running gunicorn command instead of having `CMD gunicorn ...`. This is the only possible cause I can think of now. The docker container runs well on my local machine. Not sure what's missing here since Heroku didn't give me much info for debugging

Comment: One update is that I successfully deployed this exact container to AWS ECS. Probably something is wrong with this Procfile or something else with Heroku

Comment: Seems like more of Procfile issue

Answer (score 14):

Changing from `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD` fixed this issue for me

Comment: Thank you, I had `ENTRYPOINT` because it expresses intent clearer, but all I got was their server spitting out errors from their node.js backend that I probably should never have seen...

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a `CMD` directive specified at the end of your Dockerfile.

Heroku is unclear on this in their documentation. I was able to get my container to run locally without a `CMD` directive, likely as you were. But if you read Heroku docs [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#dockerfile-commands-and-runtime) or [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml#getting-started) you'll pick up that Heroku takes for granted that the Dockerfile will specify a `CMD` to run.

I read [here](https://github.com/dpetrick/prisma-heroku) that Heroku requires all images to have the `CMD` directive specified, but I couldn't find that explicitly in Heroku docs.

I had the same problem until I added the `CMD` directive at the end of my Dockerfile. I'm still working though what exactly I should put as my `CMD` directive but I no longer get the `No command specified for process type web` error.

Here's the Docker documentation on `CMD`: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#cmd